# Is there a guarantee that the address of the object is the same?

Tags: c++

I have some base class which holds a pointer. Also I have two derived classes which are implemented as stack-allocated and dynamically allocated storage.
From those classes I need to set the pointer on the base class, for the first case - to the address of a stack allocated storage, and for the second - for dyn-allocated space.

My question is for stack-allocated case.
Example:

```
struct base { int *ptr; };

template<std::size_t N>
struct stack_allocator: base {
    int arr[N];
};
struct dyn_allocator: base {
};

template<std::size_t N>
auto make_allocator(int (&arr)[N])
   -> stack_allocator<N> // because of C++11
{
    stack_allocator<N> res;
    res.ptr = res.arr;
    printf("addr inside: %p\n", res);
    return res;
}

// using

int stack[32];
auto alloc = make_allocator(stack);
printf("addr outside: %p\n", alloc);

// will print the same address
```

I do know that `make_allocator()` can return just a copy with diff object address, but as far as I can see at least on my test and at least for now - the address is the same.

Why that happens? And how can I get guarantees that will continue to happen?

Comment: the question is unclear. `res.ptr` is just what you assign to it here `res.ptr = res.arr;` and when you print that same value in `main` then you get the same value printed

Comment: the address of the `res` and `alloc` the same in my test. `addr inside: 0x7fff1521f260
addr outside: 0x7fff1521f260`

Comment: Please post real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address of `res` is the same as `alloc` probably because of NRVO or other optimizations. I would not recommend relying on this behavior.

An easy way to achieve it portably is either by making `make_allocator` a constructor of `stack_allocator`, or by adding a reference / pointer parameter to `make_allocator` in place of the return value.

Comment: text of the questions sound as if OP is looking at the adress of the object returned from the funtion, but thats not actually the case. I don't think NRVO is relevant here. Its just a pointer value obtained from an array. Once pritned while the array is alive, and then printed when the array is gone. Actually I dont understand why OP expects the valuesto be not the same